Handling Multiple API Calls in a Carousel Slider to Prevent Data Flickering
I’m building a carousel slider that triggers an API call when a user stops on an item. However, I’m experiencing issues when the API is slow to respond. If a user quickly slides to the next item before the previous API call completes, both API responses can return simultaneously, causing a flicker in the displayed data.
Here’s what I’m trying to achieve:
Display the data for the current item without flickering.
Ensure that only the latest API call’s response is reflected in the UI.
Current Behavior:
User stops on Item 1, triggering an API call.
User slides to Item 2 before the response for Item 1 is received.
Both API responses arrive together, causing Item 1’s data to briefly display before updating to Item 2’s data.
I used Debounce to not call API for a period of time , it works when user slides items quickly without stopping at any item

Show some code.

What http client you use?
